# Implementing Real Time Search in MEAN

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mean-stack

I've developed an e-commerce app and I need to fetch key to key real time search results from MongoDB while using Angular, Node, Express, etc.

Two Questions:

**1.** Is elasticsearch my answer, if so any examples or sources to learn apart from the mongolastic module on npm directory.

**2.** I also digged around AnguarJS official website and found they are using lunrSearch. I need search results offered like Google in a    tabular format.

So far, I've put up real time search from a Json file comprising of several keywords and them hyperlinking to the real product.
My

> keywords.json

```
[
    {
        "title": "Apple",
        "Department": "Produce",
        "Category": "fruits"
    },
    {
        "title": "Orange",
        "Department": "Produce",
        "Category": "fruits"
    },
    {
        "title": "Banana",
        "Department": "Produce",
        "Category": "fruits"
    },
    {
        "title": "Cauliflower",
        "Department": "Produce",
        "Category": "vegetables"
    },
    {
        "title": "Lays",
        "Department": "Bakery",
        "Category": "chips"
    },
    {
        "title": "Olive Oil",
        "Department": "Produce",
        "Category": "oil"
    },
    {
        "title": "Shampoo",
        "Department": "PersonalCare",
        "Category": "haircare"
    }
]
```

Any npm packages, controller example, just about any advice would be helpful.

Thanks for being patient.

Comment: hey, did you find any solution for this ? I am also trying to do the same thing almost.

Comment: yes i did and i'll be happy to help you once you specify what's your stack?

Comment: okay, thanx...I am using MEAN stack for the development

Comment: https://github.com/iblong2iyush/angucomplete-alt

Comment: PM me, i'll be glad to clear more of your doubts..i know how it feels to be stuck..